# Testing IBOutlets are connected automatically or fail build on un-connected outlets

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, tdd, iboutlet

Has anyone worked out a way to automatically unit test all properties defined as `IBOutlets` on a `UIViewController` subclass are  connected after a view has been loaded (by calling `loadView`)?

My understanding is that `IBOutlet` is pre-processed out, so you loose the ability to work out which properties are `IBOutlets` at run time.

Alternatively, is there another way to force the build to fail if you have defined `IBOutlets` which are not connected?  An LLVM compiler warning option perhaps?

Comment: There are some tutorials on how to unit test uiviewcontrollers, particularly - checking IBOutlets

Comment: http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an assert which will allow you to fail hard and fast (getting your attention).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSAssert(self.myLabel, @"IBOutlet not set for self.myLabel");
}
```

You can probably wrap this up in a macro to save some typing - perhaps something like this

```
#define PASOutletAssert(outlet) NSAssert(outlet, @"IBOutlet not set for " @#outlet)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  PASOutletAssert(self.myLabel);
  PASOutletAssert(self.myOtherLabel);
}
```

Another variation to save some typing could look like this -

```
#define PASOutletsAssert(self, ...) _PASOutletsAssert(self, @"" # __VA_ARGS__)

void _PASOutletsAssert(id self, NSString *commaSeperatedKeyPaths)
{
  NSArray *keyPaths = [commaSeperatedKeyPaths componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

  for (NSString *keyPath in keyPaths) {
    NSCAssert1([self valueForKeyPath:keyPath], @"IBOutlet not set for keypath - \"%@\"", keyPath);
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  PASOutletsAssert(self, myLabel, otherLabel, yellowSquare);
}
```